# Paypal Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting this error when I go live in my PayPal account, it was working and now it stopped working suddenly, can you please help me, it's Codeigniter website.

The problem is that it works in sandbox and I don't understand what is going on, I already set off Block non-encrypted website payment,

Thanks.

UPDATE:

You can test it:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=KPEG34H4RENJA&cmd=_cart&production=1&custom=&invoice=57089&upload=1&currency_code=CAD&disp_tot=Y&cpp_cart_border_color=&no_note=1&return=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com&cancel_return=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com/panier&notify_url=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com/panier/ipn&rm=2&lc=EN&shipping=&shipping2=&handling=&tax=&discount_amount_cart=&discount_rate_cart=&first_name=&last_name=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=&zip=&email=&night_phone_a=&night_phone_b=&night_phone_c=&item_name_1=jeuxvideo&amount_1=54.95&quantity_1=1&item_name_2=expedition&amount_2=0&quantity_2=1&item_name_3=TPS-TVQ&amount_3=8.23&quantity_3=1

if you switch this to sandbox it works:

https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=9H3GUGRW23D3W&cmd=_cart&production=1&custom=&invoice=57089&upload=1&currency_code=CAD&disp_tot=Y&cpp_cart_border_color=&no_note=1&return=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com&cancel_return=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com/panier&notify_url=https://www.lesjeuxdiamant.com/panier/ipn&rm=2&lc=EN&shipping=&shipping2=&handling=&tax=&discount_amount_cart=&discount_rate_cart=&first_name=&last_name=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=&zip=&email=&night_phone_a=&night_phone_b=&night_phone_c=&item_name_1=jeuxvideo&amount_1=54.95&quantity_1=1&item_name_2=expedition&amount_2=0&quantity_2=1&item_name_3=TPS-TVQ&amount_3=8.23&quantity_3=1

[image]

Comment: What is the URL of the error page? It might have a clue, but actual help would likely require testing it or reviewing the runtime logged POST request parameters or redirect string to PayPal. These can be obtained by having the Developer Console's Network tab open, and checking the first request to a PayPal.com domain.

Comment: Hello I just updated the thread

Answer (score 0):

It appears the account in the live environment is restricted, and cannot accept any PayPal payments.

Tell the the account owner to log into https://www.paypal.com to review the restriction and the business steps needed to resolve it.

If necessary, they can reach out to PayPal's support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix Paypal Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Click image to fix bug --->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVS3q.png

OR
Add this code to form `<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">`

#HKimhab

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. That paypal page wasn't giving me any help as to what the problem might be. I found that the value of my form's hidden field sometimes exceeded the 200-character limit imposed by PayPal's policy.